# Laravel 5 routes not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a Laravel project using composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myproject.  Inside myproject routes.php has

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

welcome.blade exists in resources/views.

Inside WAMP's www is where myproject is installed. But when I type in the browser http://localhost/myproject/welcome.php it's not found?

Comment: By default Laravel expects the [Document Root](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#documentroot) to be the `public` directory of your app. If you want to run Laravel from a subdirectory, the easiest way to get that working is to setup an [Apache Virtual Host](http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the home page that's `/`, laravel will show the welcome.blade.php page. Not when you go to `welcome.php`

Also, once you install the laravel, run `php artisan serve` command in terminal or command prompt. Now you can access your web application in `localhost:8000/`

Comment: php artisan serve, is a Laravel built server, what if using only apache in WAMP?

Comment: try going to `localhost/myproject/public`

Comment: localhost/myproject/public worked pointing to the welcome.blade.php view, how is this possible when I don;t have a public route in routes.php?

Comment: Laravel's default index.php is within public folder. So all the requests will be forwarded to the public folder. So if you use the php artisan serve command, you can get rid of the public folder from the URL. But when you host your site on a remote server, you dont have to change anything. It should work.